# Can't use DocumentsContract.getDocumentId on uri gotten from ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, storage-access-framework, documentfile

From here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70933975/13519865

if I,

```kotlin
private val dirRequest = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()) { uri ->
    if (uri != null) {

DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)

}

}
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/9C33-6BBD%3AA
at android.provider.DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(DocumentsContract.java:1278)
```

I need documentId for,

```kotlin
DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, documentId)
```

Comment: The ID you get back is the `rootId`, not a `documentId` of an individual file in that directory. Is there a reason you're trying to get a documentId for a tree Uri?

Comment: List entries of that directory

Comment: You could use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri().listFiles()` to list the entries. If you do not wish to use `DocumentFile`, you could read its source code to see how it does its job.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Hi! thanks for responding. Check this function
https://github.com/google/modernstorage/blob/main/storage/src/main/java/com/google/modernstorage/storage/AndroidFileSystem.kt#L145

I tried to use this library and I got the error I mentioned.

Comment: @CyberAvater: That code is maintained by Google developers. You might wish to file a bug report with a [mcve] showing your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare your suggested method `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri().listFiles()` worked for me. Please add it as a nice answer (with any advice you have and explanations) and I'll accept it.
And regarding opening an issue for their lib, I think it's dead.
https://github.com/google/modernstorage/issues/107

Comment: I recommend that you answer your own question with your findings!

Comment: I may do that. However, your answer helped and I think you deserve the bounty.

Comment: The Google sample doesn't use `rootUri` from `OpenDocumentTree` (`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree`), but with an Uri from `okio.Path.toUri()` (probably a `file://` Uri). It's not the same as your code.